# Script to restart server if IP address binding doesn't exists

Tags: powershell

I need a script (powershell or vbs) to check if server owns IP address. If it does do nothing, if it doesn't restart server

I though I would run netstat with output to file then get the script to read the file and check for specific value (IP address)

```
if "ip address" exists in txt file then quit
if "ip address" doen't exists in txt file then retstart computer
```

I have bits of powershell but I need to join them together

First Run

```
C:>netstat -a -p tcp >c:netstat.txt
```

Then run this, if output is true quit, if output if false restart computer

```
C:>get-content c:\netstat.txt | select-string "192.168.0.1" -quiet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, here's a few.

```
# locally, check if the ip was found in the output of ipconfig
[bool] ((ipconfig) -like '*IPv4 Address*192.168.0.1*')

# ask dns
$cn = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress('192.168.0.1') | ForEach-Object {$_.HostName}

if($cn -notlike "*server1*")
{
    Restart-Computer server1 -Force
}

# get all ip addresses of a local or remote server
$ip = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName server1 | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddress}

if($ip -notcontains '192.168.0.1')
{
    Restart-Computer server1 -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sahy, the 3rd script works for my case. I appreciate the help Regards